# ASP.NET MVC getting user variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just getting started using MVC in ASP.NET, I'm going to have it so users must login to use certain features. Now I have a User controller that stores users in a table and another controller that adds data to another table. Once the user is logged in, how would I get their id from the user table from within the add controller in order to add their id to that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that to solve your problem from the top down you might want to look into ASP.NET MVC Authentication instead of implementing something like this yourself.  That said if you have a great reason for continuing down the path you're taking then I have some suggestions.

Firstly you may wish to consider using the repository pattern to add/remove/get data to and from your database.  Any controller can implement any repository it likes so your add controller can just implement the user repository to get the user.

Also, remember that in ASP.NET MVC you can use session variables.  If you need to know which user is doing what, then just store it in the session and retrieve it from there.